# Replace links in files into directory

Tags: perl, replace

I would like replace links in files on directory and sub-directories

I'm using perl command line :

```
perl -e "s/\/home\/mydir\/www/\/home\/mydir2/g;" -pi.save $(find home/dir2/dev -type f)
```

But i have an error : arg list too long

What's wrong ?

How can I replace my links in files with linux command line ?

Answer (score 3):

Seems that your `find` command will find so much files that maximum number of arguments which could be passed to a process is reached. You can find this limit on your system by typing:

```
getconf ARG_MAX
```

[Read more](http://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/argmax/)

---

**Solution**: Use the `-execdir` option of `find`

```
find home/dir2/dev -type f -execdir \
perl -e "s/\/home\/mydir\/www/\/home\/mydir2/g;" {} \;
```

This will call the perl command for every file instead of passing all file names as argument to perl. Additionally it prevents you from problems with spaces in file names and some potential security issues (in opposite to `-exec`)

Comment: Ok thanks it looks great, but nothing replace on my sub directories and is not verbose

Comment: why not using `sed`? should I give an example?

Comment: please give me an exemple

Comment: replace the `perl` cmd by `sed -i 's/\/home\/mydir\/www/\/home\/mydir2/g'` .. But be careful. I would try it in a copy of the original files first..

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have already been given a good solution to your problem.

I wanted to suggest a small improvement to your Perl. The substitution operator (`s/.../.../`) will accept alternative delimiters in order to make code clearer.

So where you have:

```
s/\/home\/mydir\/www/\/home\/mydir2/g
```

You can rewrite it as:

```
s|/home/mydir/www|/home/mydir2|g
```

Which looks clearer to you?